# Determining the self-assigned IP address of a directly-connected counterpart

Tags: windows, networking

I have connected two computers, A and B, NIC-to-NIC using an ethernet cable.  They have self-assigned their IP addresses—at least, I can see that A has done so, so I infer that B must have also done so. Computer A is a laptop running Windows 10, but I have no keyboard and mouse available for B.   From A, how can I determine B's IP address?

On A, this is what I see:

```
> ipconfig

Ethernet adapter Ethernet

    Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address.  . : 169.254.219.59
    Subnet Mask .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . : 255.255.0.0
```

What I've tried (based on https://serverfault.com/a/30742):

```
> nmap -sn 169.254.219.0/24
```

...which just says "Host is up" and doesn't report anybody else being on the network. I don't claim to understand what `nmap` is doing (for example, I have no idea what's special about the number 24) but I do know that the same command with `192.168.1.0/24` successfully finds devices on the wireless network to which A is also attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for example, I have no idea what's special about the number 24

It's a short way of writing the "255.255.255.0" netmask. (Also called "CIDR syntax" from its origins, or "prefix length" because it indicates that the network is specified by the first 24 bits. If you convert 255.255.255.0 from decimal to binary, you'll see it begins with exactly 24 'one' bits.)

However, your *actual* netmask is not 255.255.255.0 – it's 255.255.0.0, as shown in the ifconfig output. That's a /16. The whole "self-assigned" range is in fact 169.254.0.0/16.

---

Hosts will send out a few ARP probes as part of the self-assignment process (to ensure that the address isn't already in use). If you connect the computers while Wireshark or tcpdump is already running a capture on the Ethernet interface, you should see both of them revealing their addresses this way.

Comment: Relative to everything else I had so far stumbled across, this is a stunningly intelligible explanation of the `/24` - thanks.   So I conclude that `nmap -sn 169.254.0.0/16` would be the way to go.   I actually managed the equivalent of that in the end by adapting one of the `nmap --help` examples to `nmap -sn 169.254.0-255.0-255` and found the IP by letting it run for 45 minutes.   In future I'll bear in mind the `tcpdump` tip.     I presume there's no way of unilaterally configuring A to say "hey, let's self assign, but with a 24-bit prefix"?  That would make it a lot quicker to find...

Comment: No, this autoconf mechanism (APIPA) is defined to always use this specific /16 prefix. However, the idea was that it would be accompanied by other Zeroconf services such as mDNS for dynamic discovery. (For example, Windows has mDNS and a few similar alternatives, so as long as both computers run Windows and have the network mode set to “private” you should be able to reach the other computer by its name without needing the exact address. Same goes for macOS and (to some extent) Linux.)

Comment: But to answer the question, if you specifically wanted to change the prefix, you would have to run DHCP in order to do that instead of relying on autoconf. (And once you have DHCP you no longer *need* nmap nor tcpdump, as you can just look in the DHCP server’s “lease” table to find the address...)